# How to prove: 1. (A^B)v(A^C) 2. (AvD) -> E //E

Tags: deduction, propositional-logic

This proof has stumped me. It seems that getting (AvD) alone then using Modens ponens to therefore prove E would be the correct way of going about things but I cannot seem to find a way to get (AvD) alone.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza, that depends on the rules of inference allowed. I can prove this using Copi rules. In particular there is a rule called "distribution" along with a few others that must be used here. I don't need to make any assumptions to do so either. Using natural deduction basic rules is not enough. More advanced rules would be required. The copi rules used to be taught in philosophy. The basic intro & elimination rules in natural deduction are included inside the Copi rules, But they go by different names.

Comment: "natural deduction basic rules **is** enough". Use Disjunction Elimination with 1) to derive **A**. Then **(A v D)** will follow by Disjunction Introduction.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Seems to be a trend on the site towards dealing with the mechanics of proofs from toy problems in texts. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to deduce the A by itself. Once you can deduce A alone you can use the or introduction rule. Now of course that begs the question WHAT RULES ARE YOU ALLOWED TO USE?

Different courses in logic can use different sets of rules. Logic taught in mathematics can differ from logic taught in philosophy classes.

If you were taught Copi rules this deduction is possible. The same rules could be found in Patrick Hurley logic text.  Hurley has 18 while Copi has 19 rules of inference. Both text summarizes the rules at the back cover of their text books for easy reference.

You would need the transposition rule (Math people call this different aka contraposition), you would need a commutation rule (this rule allows you to change the order of variables) you would also need the distribution rule, you will finally need the addition rule (aka the or introduction rule).

1  (A & B) V (A & C)
2  (A V D) --> E           /therefore  E.

---

3  [ (A & B) V A ] & [ ( A & B) V C ]

4  [ A V (A & B) ] & [ C V (A & B) ]

5  [ (A V A) & (A V B) ] & [ (C V A) & (CVB)]

6  [  (A V A) & ( AVB) ]

7  [  A   &  (A V B) ]

8. A.
9. A V D.
10. E.
    ■QED.

Of course I could be mistaken here. I presented the proof without using the inference rule names.  That is what the OP has to figure out.  I stated the rules can be found in Copi text or Hurley's text in the back cover. If I am mistaken anyone can correct me. That is what this is supposed to be about. Not showing off how smart one is or humiliating some one who makes a mistake. If there are mistakes we can SEE PRECISELY WHERE THEY ARE and fix it from there.
So my focus is more on the method of the system and not the results.  This makes the system a checks and balance system where anyone can input. Humans can err so having a checks and balance system helps with our confidence in knowledge.